# Android widgets not showing on screen

Tags: java, android, android-widget

I am trying to make a simple `widget` but when I want to put it in the screen it just disappear.
I tried this on Api : 23,26 and 30 ,it's all give me the same result.

**Manifest.xml**

```
<receiver android:name=".mAppWidgetProvider">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget_info"/>

    </receiver>
```

**widget_info.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:configure="com.app24.test.mAppWidgetProvider"
android:initialLayout="@layout/my_widget"
android:minWidth="250dp"
android:minHeight="70dp"
android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
android:updatePeriodMillis="10000"
android:widgetCategory="home_screen">
</appwidget-provider>
```

**mAppWidgetProvider**

```
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;

public class mAppWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

}
```

**my_widget (the layout)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@color/white"
android:padding="8dp">

<TextView
    android:text="Hello world"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<Button
    android:text="Click me!"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<Button
    android:text="Click me!"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**and I have tried the other solutions but no thing.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out logcat and look for some `Exception`. App widgets are crashing "silently" without any dialog, just doesn't appear. But you should be able to find cause of problem in logs

in your code I see one wrong line:

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ...
    android:configure="com.app24.test.mAppWidgetProvider"
    ...
```

[`android:configure` should point on some `Activity`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets#Configuring), which will be started when your widget will be added to home screen. your line points wrongly on your custom `AppWidgetProvider`, which isn't an `Acticity` - system probably tries to start this class as `Activity` or maybe checks `instanceof` and as this class isn't `Activity` then crash occurs. try to remove this line for start (or point on proper class)

Comment: I removed that line and it worked finally !,thank you so much...